# Property of a normally convergence squence of functions

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let the terms of a function sequence $\{f_n\}$ be continuous in an open set $U \subseteq \mathbb{C}$.  If $\{f_n\}$ converges normally in $U$ to the limit function $f$ and if $z_n \to z_0$ in $U$, then $f_n(z_n)\to f(z_0)$ in $U$.

Since $\{f_n\}$ is normally convergent, this means that it converges uniformly on every compact set $K \subset U$. Also, $z_n \to z$ uniformly on each $K$.

I'm not sure how to pull these two pieces of information together to prove the above assertion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $$|f_n(z_n)-f(z_0)|\le |f_n(z_n)-f(z_n)|+|f(z_n)-f(z_0)|\le\|f_n-f\|_K+|f(z_n)-f(z_0)|$$
for a suitable $K$.

Comment: I don't understand the notation on the double modulus at the end of the inequality.

Comment: @abet: I meant the sup-norm on $K$, i.e. $\|g\|_K = \sup_{z\in K} |g(z)|$.

Comment: I want to see if I can fill in all the details.  Let $z_0 \in K \subseteq U$.  Since $f_n$ converges normally in $U$, it converges uniformly on $K$.  Let $\epsilon >0$, then there exists an $N$ such that for $n \geq N$, we have $|f_n(z_n)-f(z_n)|+|f(z_n)+f(z_0)|$.  The left portion of the sum is less than $\epsilon/2$ for sufficiently large $n$ since $f_n$ is uniformly convergent on $K$.  The right hand side is bounded by $\epsilon/2$ since $f$ is continuous since $f_n$ is uniformly convergent on $K$.  Hence $|f_n(z_n)-f(z_0)|<\epsilon$.

Comment: @abet yes, that looks good